# String replace() fails

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I used the replace() function to remove the _pc and keep the 1, but it's not working...

```
function testing()
{
    var code = "a1_pc"; //The initial stuff
    alert(code); //Printing -> a1_pc

    var number = code.split("a"); //Remove the "a"
    alert(number); //Printing again -> ,1_pc

    number = number.slice(1); //Remove the ","
    alert(number); //Printing again -> 1_pc

    number = number.replace("_pc", "");
    alert(number); //Returns nothing...
}
```

Comment: Both should work, can you show more code?

Comment: It works...do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Yep. The problem is elsewhere. Can you provide an example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: it is absolutely working...`ctrl+shift+c` and try it out in the console

Comment: Its works and i copy/paste your code

Comment: The code you give is correct: https://jsfiddle.net/jwhnsLcf/

Comment: Proof of it working http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hm3my587/

Comment: For the record, that will convert it into a string, just one that happens to contain a numeral. If you want to convert anything like *someNumber_someText* into a number you can do `parseInt(value, 10)`. It's not *always* the best approach but it works in the simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your above solution should work perfectly and does so in the example below.

The problem must lay somewhere else within your code.

```js
var text = '1_pc';
text = text.replace("_pc", "");
console.log(text);
```

if you are certain it is the `replace()` function causing the problems, you can use either of these 2 alternatives.

---

If you know that the last 3 characters are always `_pc`, you could use `substring` to find all the other characters instead.

```js
var text = '1_pc';
text = text.substring(0, text.length - 3);
console.log(text);
```

---

Or very similiar to the solution above, you could use `slice` which is essentially a much cleaner version of the `substring` solution.

```js
var text = '1_pc';
text = text.slice(0, -3);
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use split() javascript function and get first occurrence of string.
split("string which you want to",limit as 1 for first occurrence only)

```
var res = text.split("_",1);
```

it will return 1

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is why is `replace` not working. The answer is that it *is*